# Mixing Knockout with D3 - updating the view

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, d3.js

I'm a noob w/ Knockout and D3 (Data Driven Documents) and what I'm trying to do is create an array of JS objects that I make D3 display. Right now I just display some words in an HTML span tag. What I'm trying to do is make the name that gets displayed a KO observable that if I change farther down line (the date[0].name line), the view gets those changes. For some reason, the last line doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm theorizing that I'm missing something when I'm generating the HTML and KO doesn't know how to find the correct location to change. I added an "attr(x, y)" call to the end of the d3.select chain to try to add a data-bind attribute but I think that KO requires those to be unique (but I'm not sure). Any help is appreciated.

```
var data = [
        { "id": "1", "name": ko.observable("alpha"), ...
        { "id": "2", "name": ko.observable("bravo"), ...
        { "id": "3", "name": ko.observable("delta"), ...
];

ko.applyBindings(data);

d3.select("body").selectAll("span")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("span")
.text(
    function (d) {
        return d.name();
    }
);  

data[0].name('october');
```

Comment: You would have to make Knockout D3-aware for this to work. Even in pure D3 this won't work because you're only updating the data, not the elements.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand what problems knockout is trying to solve. Knockouts whole purpose (without needing other libraries) is to keep HTML updated with data.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. D3 provides the visualization which I wanted to keep up to date w/ Knockout. Lars comment however states that this isn't possible.

Comment: those observables in your data is going to help you at all. I could copy paste from here for you but here is the link: http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2013/06/23/dynamic-d3-with-knockout-js/

Answer (score 1):

If you want Knockout to work together with d3, you need to apply the knockout bindings to each individual element that you create:

```
var data = [
    { "id": "1", "name": ko.observable("alpha") },
    { "id": "2", "name": ko.observable("bravo") },
    { "id": "3", "name": ko.observable("delta") }
];

d3.select("body").selectAll("span")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("span")
    .attr("data-bind", "text: name") // Applies the data binding attribute
    .each(function (d) {
        ko.applyBindings(d, this); // Sets up Knockout to work with the node
    });

data[0].name('october');
```

You only need to apply these bindings once - when you change the node, the data binding still applies. In fact, if you are reapplying bindings to an already existing node, you must first call `ko.cleanNode()` to get rid of the first bindings.

If you want to get this data from your view model in whatever your binding context is, either use something like `ko.dataFor()` to get the binding on the parent element:

```
var data = ko.dataFor(d3.select("#parent-to-attach-to").node());
```

or explicitly subscribe to the binding:

```
viewModel.observableIWantToTrack.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // your d3 update code here, using newValue
}
```

or create a [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that calls it up:

```
ko.bindingHandler.whateverYouWantToCallYourHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       // any initialization logic you need
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       // where you perform your actual updates
    }
}
```

Use whatever solution suits your situation best.

One more note: bindings do not re-evaluate, which is why you have to call `ko.applyBindings()`. This is probably OK for normal bindings, like `if` and even `with`, though you will want to watch for them. What they are not OK for are `foreach` bindings - if you attempt to evaluate a foreach binding after inserting your data-bound d3 elements, Knockout will compound the elements that you placed and cause a lot of problems. It is best to allow d3's native data join behavior do what knockout's `foreach` does normally.